# Will full-text search index be limited in size?

Tags: google-app-engine

We are about to migrate our app to FTS to replace datastore indexes.
Will there be a limit in index size once the FTS is our of experimental state or is it unlimited like the datastore?

Comment: i'd be curious to know this too, since our app is approaching the index limit and apparently it's not trivial for google to up the count for your app even if you are willing to pay for it.

Comment: """is it unlimited like the datastore""" Actually there is some limits for the datastore indexes, currently: `Maximum number of values in all indexes for an entity: 5000`, `Number of Indexes: 200`, see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Datastore

Comment: I've been talking to the developers at Google IO and it looks as if the indexes are not limited in size. They are not built on top of the datastore but on the megastore and leverage the Google search backends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [App Engine version 1.9.0](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes): "The size limit on the Search API is now computed and enforced on a per-index basis, rather than for the app as a whole. The per-index limit is now 10GB. There is no fixed limit on the number of indexes, or on the total amount of Search API storage an application may use."

Answer (score 3):

Once the Search API is out of experimental, there should be no limit on index size.